# Selecting models through Rails relations?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have these (simplified) models:

```
Address
public (Boolean)
has_one :group_member

Group
has_many :Group_Members
belongs_to :User

Group_Member
belongs_to :group
belongs_to :address

User
has_many :groups
```

I want to select all addresses where `public` is true and all the addresses which User can access through Groups.

I assume it's something along the lines of:

```
Address.where(public: TRUE).joins(:group_member)
```

Am I somewhere close?

I'm using Rails 4 and PostgreSQL as my database if it helps anyone.

Comment: did you mean `Address` instead of `Model?`

Comment: Oh yeah I did, thanks for noticing! :)

Comment: public is a reserved word in ruby, you probably want to use an attribute like is_public.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewKuklewicz, that'd probably caused me lots of pain

Comment: are you trying to access `addresses` for a particular user or any user?

Comment: If a user is logged in, I want all the none-public addresses that he has access to through groups + the public addresses

Comment: @DanAndreasson..curious about how much faster is the join query compared to the eager loading ?...I was not expecting it to be faster so want to understand it. Would appreciate if you can pastebin the query log for the join query as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
Address.joins(group_member: :group).where(is_public: true, groups: {user_id: 12345})
```

Let's break this down.

First we are calling on the `Address` model, b/c that is what we want to return.

`.joins(:group_member)` will join addresses to `group_members` via the `Address` `has_one :group_member` relation.

However, we actually want to go further, and join the `group` connected with the `group_member`, so we use a nested join, which is why it looks like this `joins(group_member: :group)` to indicate that we join address -> group_member, then group_member -> group.

Next the where clause.  There are 2 conditions, we want:

1. Public addresses only, which is indicated as a column on the address, so we add this:
   `.where(is_public: true)`.
2. We want only where a particular user is connected with a group (and so its group_members and addresses). For this we need to add a nested where clause, like so `groups: {user_id: 12345}`.

The result of combining these is:

`where(is_public: true, groups: {user_id: 12345})`

So all together, the line of code above should get what you want.

Comment: "Association named 'groups' was not found on Address" is what I get

Comment: so you need to add the other end of that relation - Address belongs_to :group_member

Comment: But an address does not have any groups. Could you explain your code a bit please?

Comment: ah, didn't nest the joins, edited. Also, look at this example: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-nested-associations-single-level

Comment: Still kinda same problem; Address does not have group_member_id in it. It's group_member model who has group_id and address_id. Do you think I need to rethink how I have organized it?

Comment: That makes no sense then. If GroupMember has_one address, then address  has to have a group_member_id. If it was GroupMember belongs_to address, then GroupMember would have an address_id on it.   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association  so replace Supplier with GroupMember, and Account with Address - see what I mean? either your keys or your relations are wrong.

Comment: I'll update the question and fix that. The relations are wrong. 

Group_member does indeed have address_id and group_id in it

Comment: Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: I have added more explanation to my answer, but I think it's close to right already, so long as the models have the relations described.

Comment: IT WORKS! Finally! Thanks a lot for hanging in there!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following -- it is not a single query but I think it is better than a single query with big join table:

```
public_addresses = Address.where(is_public: true)
# =>  get all public addresses

user_addresses = current_user.groups.includes(:group_members => :address).
                # includes is to eager load records to avoid N+1 queries
                flat_map{|g| g.group_members.map(&:address)}
                # inner block returns array of addresses for each group
                # flat_map converts the array of arrays to single level 
# => get all addresses associated with the user


all_addresses = (public_addresses + user_addresses).uniq
# =>  remove duplicates
```

To speed up the query add indices for slower queries. For e.g

```
   add_index :groups, :user_id
   # this speeds up finding groups for a given user

   add_index :group_members, :group_id
   # this speeds up finding group_members for a given group

   add_index :addresses, :group_member_id
   # this speeds up finding addresses for a given group_member
```

Other Options is to get `user_addresses` using `join` tables

```
   user_addresses = Address.joins(group_member: group).where(groups: {user_id: current_user.id} )
```

Comment: "Could not find the association :group_members in mode User"

Comment: did u try `User` or `user`?

Comment: updated so that it is more clear...`current_user` is the user who is logged in

Comment: I'm sorry. That association was a error by me. I didn't realize that I had to restart the rails console

Comment: The only problem now is that it isn't that quick. If you come up with something that is faster I would love to know

Comment: @DanAndreasson updated the answer. To speed up the query add indices on slower queries.

Comment: thanks for that. I'll have to read up on what add_index actually does.

Comment: @DanAndreasson see the docs [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index)...this needs to go in a db migration.

Comment: I get how to implement it, but I am not quite sure what it does

Comment: ohhh..lots of articles on that, for e.g. see this [one](http://blog.evanweaver.com/2007/02/12/table-indexes-in-rails/)

Comment: It speeds it up a bit, but it seems that it is the flat_map function which adds the majority of the time (~4000ms)

Comment: can you post the server log in pastebin?

Comment: hmmm....the time is taken in loading the records from db....but it is strange as a query based on address`ids` which is the primary key is taking 4000 ms. Not sure why..try debugging using `explain` as shown [here](http://over9000.org/rails/some-postgresql-advice-for-rails-programmers)

Comment: @DanAndreasson added a second option using `join` tables, see if that works and is faster.